# jsessionid not getting recorded on JMeter

Tags: jmeter, oracle-adf

The jsessionid in not getting recorded in Apache JMeter while trying to record an ADF Application. The jsessionid cookie name has been changed to something els. Will this effect the recording of sessions in anyway?

I am following the below link to configure JMeter for Oracle's ADF 11g.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cudvV12KGiQ

Comment: I do not think this is a problem, but can you please explain to what it is changed? Where did you detect this? Give some more info

Comment: I guess you right. The cookie name has been defaulted, but the JMeter recording still doesn't capture the jsessionid details. I cleared the browsing data as well and tried, but its still not recording.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://one-size-doesnt-fit-all.blogspot.it/2010/04/configuring-apache-jmeter-specifically.html) old post by Chris Muir explains how to configure Jmeter specifically for ADF 11g.

The problem could be the jsessionId is not saved as a cookie but stored in the request query instead.